# Having an issue with callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

So I have some code like this

```js
const getAPIData = (symbol, callback) => {
  var options = {
    url: "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price",
    method: "GET",
    qs: {
      symbol
    },
  };
  request(options, (err, res, body) => {
    body = JSON.parse(body);
    callback(body);
  });
};

var isValid = 0;
getAPIData(symbol, (body) => {
  console.log(body);
  if (body.symbol) {
    console.log("yes");
    isValid = 1;
  } else {
    console.log("no");
  }
});
```

After this callback is executed the "isValid" variable still remains 0 no matter what the outcome is. Although the console gets logged with yes and no both. The isValid variable still remains 0 when I debug the program.

How can the console.log function work and not set the isValid to 1? it's like it's just skipping that line or I'm not sure. Please help me out!

Comment: where did you print the value of isValid  in the code?

Comment: If have a conditional right under this function it checks if isValid > 0 (which always gets rejected cause isValid is always 0 for some reason. I also debugged the program in VSCode and shows the same

Comment: Put that conditional in the callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way asynchronous calls work.

```
  var isValid = 0;
  getAPIData(symbol, (body) => {
    console.log(body);
    if (body.symbol) {
      console.log("yes");
      isValid = 1;
      console.log(isValid); // 1
    } else {
      console.log("no");
    }
  });

console.log(isValid); // 0
// when the JS engine gets here, isValid will still be 0
// since getAPIData is asynchronous and it's still in progress at this point
// also, you cannot use any results of getAPIData here
```

Comment: As a side note, you should be using `boolean` type to store true/false flags, not number.

Comment: Thank you its working now, but if the flag set is only valid within the async function. How to set a flag globally so that i can use it to run conditionals outside the function? Or does it not work that way?

Comment: You can set any flag globally, but the change will only be visible to the following code in the async callback. So all the return data handling logic must be placed in the callback. This can quickly end up being a so-called 'callback hell' if there are other async steps in the flow, but there are ways to refactor it to a cleaner form by using promise chains or async-await syntax.